# About Settings.settings in C#

Tags: c#

How can I program to set up Settings.settings to show error messages in my program?

```
private void Go2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[,] i_Array;
    int result1 = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
    int result2 = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
    i_Array=new int[result1,result2];
    int result3 =  int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
    int total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < i_Array.Length; i++)
    {
        total +=result3;
        textBox6.Text = Convert.ToString(total);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. Do you want to allow the settings file to define bounds for some properties (like retry attempts, or valid ranges of values)? Do you want it to store some error strings for certain types of errors?

Comment: yes,I want to store some error strings for checking textboxes.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea what this is asking. What is `Settings.settings`? What error messages? What does the code you posted have to do with anything? What does any of this have to do with Visual Studio? In the comment you said "store some error strings for checking textboxes", what does that mean? Can you edit in an example? I'm not going to vote to close yet because I believe you have a legitimate question, but think of it from our point of view, you have to give us enough information to answer your question.

Comment: If you want to store error messages (or any other text displayed to the user) separate from the code (which is a good idea, too often not done...bravo :) ), you should store them as resources, preferably in a localized resource DLL. There are a number of resources on MSDN describing how to do that; it's too broad to explain here...you should investigate, make an attempt, and then if you have trouble come back with a _specific_ question.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you should save strings in a resource file, not a settings file. Settings files are more for configurable settings for your project, and error messages are not typically user-configurable.

Let me also add that the sample below is NOT how I would recommend validating an int from the user. You should use `int.TryParse()` instead of `int.Parse()`, and you should handle invalid input on a case by case basis, using a validator.

But that was not your question, so here's one way you could add a setting and read it in code:

**Add a Settings File**

In Visual Studio, go to Project -> Add New Item, Choose 'Settings File' and Click 'Add'.

**Add a Setting**

In your Solution Explorer, double-click the new 'Settings1.settings' file (or whatever you named it), and add a setting by giving a Name, Type, Scope, and Value in the dialog.
For this example, let's use:

1. Name = StringIsNotAnInt
2. Type = string
3. Scope = User
4. Value = The string you entered is not a valid integer.

**Read the Setting in Code**

You can wrap your code in a `try` block, and then `catch` the type of exception you want to display a custom message for. For example, add the following changes to your code above:

```
private void Go2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int[,] i_Array;
        int result1 = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
        int result2 = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
        i_Array = new int[result1, result2];
        int result3 = int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
        int total = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < i_Array.Length; i++)
        {
            total += result3;
            textBox6.Text = Convert.ToString(total);
        }
    }
    catch (FormatException e)
    {
        // Try to read the message from user settings
        string errorMessage = Settings1.Default.StringIsNotAnInt;

        // If there wasn't a setting, then use the default error message
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(errorMessage))
        {
            errorMessage = e.Message;
        }

        // Show the message to the user
        MessageBox.Show(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From the menu select Project Properties. Click on Settings then the link "This project does not ...". Setting will now appear under project properties and the Settings designer will be open.